# How to mount File Share to an Azure Container Apps Environment in Bicep?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-storage, azure-bicep, azure-container-apps

Currently, I am facing a problem with mounting a File Share to Azure Container App Environment.

The problem is that volume mounting is not idempotent and if the volume mount with the same name already exists, on running the pipeline and bicep I get an error:

**Invalid request body for managed environment storage 'storageMountName'. Only 'properties.azureFile.AccountKey' can be updated**

My bicep module:

```
param storageName string
param storageMountName string
param storageFileShareName string
param ACAEnvironmentResourceName string
@secure()
param storageAccountKey string

resource containerEnvironment 'Microsoft.App/managedEnvironments@2023-05-01' existing = {
  name: ACAEnvironmentResourceName
}

resource qdrantstorage 'Microsoft.App/managedEnvironments/storages@2023-05-01' = {
  parent: containerEnvironment
  name: storageMountName
  properties: {
    azureFile: {
      accountName: storageName
      shareName: storageFileShareName
      accountKey: storageAccountKey
      accessMode: 'ReadWrite'
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried mounting a volume with a unique name and there is no issue at all, everything runs smoothly.
The problem is when I try to 're-mount' the volume.
I get why it could be a problem, but that behavior makes the bicep template `'Microsoft.App/managedEnvironments/storages@2023-05-01'` idempotent.

What I am currently trying is to find a workaround in which I can check if a mounted volume with the given name already exists, if it does I will make the step of mounting conditional.

Please note just, I am new to bicep and if my approach is wrong let me know.

Comment: what error are you getting? are you able to create a Container App Environment at all with out the storage part?

Comment: Hello, the Container App Environment is already pre-created for me. 
I just need to mount a file share volume to it.

When I try to mount the volume for the  first time it works perfectly, when I try to re-run the bicep a second time it fails with error: **Invalid request body for managed environment storage 'storageMountName'. Only 'properties.azureFile.AccountKey' can be updated**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see in your Bicep code, you are trying to mount File Share to an Azure Container Apps Environment in Bicep. I can not see your storage creation information. In other words, `'Microsoft.App/managedEnvironments/storages@2023-05-01'` does not either create a storage account or file share, or/and one of your storage parameter names has a capital letter, as mentioned in note one below.

With that said you need to add the missing elements, so something like the following is a working example:

```
var storageName = 'uniquenamemax24chr'
var shareName = 'share'
var mountName = 'storagemountname'

resource containerEnvironment 'Microsoft.App/managedEnvironments@2023-05-01' existing = {
  name: ACAEnvironmentResourceName
}

resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2023-01-01' = {
  name: storageName 
  location: location
  kind: 'Storage'
  sku: {
    name: 'Standard_LRS'
  }
}

resource fileService 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/fileServices/shares@2023-01-01' = {
  name: '${storageAccount.name}/default/${shareName}'
  properties: {}
}

resource qdrantstorage 'Microsoft.App/managedEnvironments/storages@2023-05-01' = {
  parent: containerEnvironment
  name: mountName
  properties: {
    azureFile: {
      accountName: storageName 
      shareName: shareName 
      accountKey: storageAccount.listKeys().keys[0].value
      accessMode: 'ReadWrite'
    }
  }
}
```

If you have the storage account and file storage created already, you can use the same concept you could either pass it as a parameter or use existing to fetch the object of storage and pass the required variables.

Notes

1. the storage naming conventions, should always be small letters. So all parameters like `accountname`, `sharename`, and `mountname` should be small letters.
2. When I deploy my solution, I use incremental mode.

And it works, here are the final results:

[image]

Comment: Hello Maytham, thanks for the answer, but it does not solve my problem.

1. I didn't explicitly say that, but I create the storage account in the previous module. 

2. As I mentioned, this approach works for me as well, it creates the storage mount, but only the first time I run the bicep. If I ran it second time it fails.

What I would suggest is, try to run the same bicep you provided me second time, than you will get the error message: **Invalid request body for managed environment storage 'storageMountName'. Only 'properties.azureFile.AccountKey' can be updated**

Comment: I have re run my bicep and no issues at all

Comment: Did you use the same mount name and in what mode did you run the bicep, incremental or complete?

Comment: Hey Maytham, that is strange. Thanks for trying to help me, I will try to run your script and try to dig deeper into it. If I have any more findings or I find the solution I will update the question.

Comment: Indeed it's working.